# When to use Excel versus R

Tags: r, excel

I've realized the hard way that plotting things like dual y-axis plots is faster in Excel than in R but calculating means for spaghetti plots is easier to do in R than in Excel. In general, when's it faster to use Excel than to use R to do things besides doing multiple linear regression where I'd obviously use R?

What kind of plotting or non-regression hypothesis testing is faster in R than in Excel?

Comment: This question is too broad and is based on users experience. My bias is always use R. You can reuse R scripts, adjust them to new situations, etc. In Excel, you have to recreate things by hand.

Comment: Even statements about timings are contentious. Take a beginner in one and an expert in another....

Comment: It is very subjective. As an opinion: *never* use excel for multiple reasons. Using R or python speed will increase in time, and one do not cut powerful possibilities of data processing, visualisation and modelling. You do not learn mostly useless tool. You learn skills valued at job market. Many to count...

Answer (score 1):

This question might get closed for involving opinions, but here are my thoughts:

It is usually *faster* to use the program you are used to.

But, for statistical problems, including graphs, it is usually *better* to use R. The default choices for graphs in Excel are often awful and Excel makes it easy to make really bad graphs.

For instance, you mention dual axis graphs. These are often problematic (as William Cleveland pointed out in one of his books). They are easy to manipulate to get the graph to show what you want to see (or show).

It is *possible* to make wonderful graphs in Excel, but it is hard.

Within R, many people love the ggplot package. It is true that once you get used to it, ggplot makes it easy to make good graphs and hard to make bad ones. A huge amount of thought went into ggplot. But, personally, I like base graphs and the lattice package. This may be because I have not spent enough time with ggplot.

I find the quest for speed in making graphs somewhat troublesome. Although it varies depending on their purpose, really good graphs cannot be made quickly, just as really good text cannot be written quickly. It's one thing to make a quick graph for yourself to look at as part of a larger data analysis. But if you are making a graph for publication or presentation, allot time to make the graph good. They say "a picture is worth a thousand words" - well, some graphs would take a lot more than a thousand words to describe.  But if you were writing a thousand words you would know that those words need editing. So do graphs.